# How do I stop Django from logging PermissionDenied exceptions?

Tags: python-3.x, django, logging

My custom middleware raises a PermissionDenied exception in certain cases to return a 403 response to the client. I believe this is the "correct" way to do this. Unfortunately it also logs the exception with a traceback every time this happens, even with `DEBUG` set to False.

> 2023-05-08 10:27:25,293 WARNING django.request Forbidden (Permission denied): /
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/project/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
> response = get_response(request)
> File "/opt/project/myapp/middleware.py", line 112, in **call**
> raise PermissionDenied
> django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied

I don't care about these exceptions. Is there a simple way to prevent them from being logged?

Comment: Do you never care about the Traceback of django.request, or do you care in cases when it is not that specific "Forbidden (Permission denied)" error?

Comment: If you don't care about the exception, why are you raising it?

Comment: I don't care that a user hit a URL they're not authorized for (my apache logs will show that) and I don't need a traceback gunking up the logs for it. If there's a better way to do a 403 without raising an exception I'd like to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple options to achieve what you want:

Case A: You **never** care about the traceback of django.request.

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '{name} {levelname} {asctime} {module} {process:d} {thread:d} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
        'custom': {
            'format': '{name} {levelname} {asctime} {module}',  # delete here what you don't want to be logged
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {  # define your django.request logger here
            'handlers': ['your_handler'],  # replace as you need it
            'level': 'INFO',  # replace as you need it
            'propagate': False,  # makes that django.request logs are not being logged by django general logger
            'formatter': 'custom'  # send these logs to your setup formatter
        }
    },
}
```

In case it is not self explanatory: Search for the big dicitonary called `LOGGING` inside your settings.py. Here you add the logger django.request to your loggers. It is included to your logging by default, but you need to add it, to give more specifications, since you don't want to see the exceptions.

After adding the django.request logger, you assign your custom formatter to it. That custom formatter differs from the verbose formatter. Differences are that process, thread and **message** are not being logged! Sure you can adjust that to your needs and also delete the time or whatever.

Bare in mind that this is not specifically for your Permission denied errors! It is then set for all logs by django.request (also the 5xx).

Case B: You **specifically** want to get rid of the Permission denied errors

```py
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
def skip_permission_denied(record):
    if record.exc_info:
        exc_type, exc_value = record.exc_info[:2]
        if isinstance(exc_value, PermissionDenied):
            return False
    return True
```

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '{name} {levelname} {asctime} {module} {process:d} {thread:d} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'filters': ['skip_permission_denied'],
            '()': 'django.utils.log.CallbackFilter',
            'callback': skip_permission_denied,
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {  # define your django.request logger here
            'handlers': ['your_handler'],  # replace as you need it
            'level': 'INFO',  # replace as you need it
            'filters': ['skip_permission_denied'],  # assign this filter to logger
            'propagate': False,  # makes that django.request logs are not being logged by django general logger
        }
    },
}
```

Define custom filter [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/logging/#django.utils.log.CallbackFilter). This will skip every permission denied error issued by the django.request logger.

Let me know how this works out for you.